# selenium driver.findElements() returns a promise instead of element

Tags: node.js, selenium, promise

I have a node app (on linux with selenium Chrome headless), where I have a simple method as depicted in code below:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
   .forBrowser('chrome')
   .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments('--headless'))
   .build();


async function getElementWithClassnameFromPageLoadedInDriver(eleClassname, curDriver){

   let arrElements = await curDriver.findElements(By.className(eleClassname));

   return arrElements[0];
}


async function test(url){

   await driver.get(url);

   let ele = await getElementWithClassnameFromPageLoadedInDriver("myClassForH2Tag", driver);  

   console.log( util.inspect(ele) );
   // prints the following:
   /*
      WebElement {
        driver_: 
         thenableWebDriverProxy {
           session_: Promise { [Object] },
           executor_: Executor { w3c: true, customCommands_: [Object], log_: [Object] },
           fileDetector_: null,
           onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
           then: [Function: bound then],
           catch: [Function: bound catch] },
        id_: Promise { '612338d3-b812-42f7-99e3-533ea33f85bc' } }
   */

   ele.getText(); 
   // causes a crash with error ....  .getText() is not a function

   return ele;
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of tags like **h2** , **p** by providing the classname.
I've been at this for several hours now and have tried adding **sleep** (didn't want to) , **then()** but nothing works.

Please advice on how to resolve this. I'd like to stick with async/await so the code is easier read.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementWithClassnameFromPageLoadedInDriver` is async function so you need to await it before getting the output. Like this

```
async function test(url){

   await driver.get(url);

   let ele = await getElementWithClassnameFromPageLoadedInDriver("myClassForH2Tag", driver);  

   console.log( util.inspect(ele) );
   // prints the following:
   /*
      WebElement {
        driver_: 
         thenableWebDriverProxy {
           session_: Promise { [Object] },
           executor_: Executor { w3c: true, customCommands_: [Object], log_: [Object] },
           fileDetector_: null,
           onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
           then: [Function: bound then],
           catch: [Function: bound catch] },
        id_: Promise { '612338d3-b812-42f7-99e3-533ea33f85bc' } }
   */

   ele.getText(); 
   // causes a crash with error ....  .getText() is not a function

   return ele;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish. That's my bad, I do have the await keyword, and it was removed to simplify the code before posting on SO. For some reason it still is returning a promise and not the element.

Answer (score 0):

The response I was getting as promise was the correct response. I was just trying to call a method that did not exist for P and H2 tags.

Instead of .getText() I should have called .getAttribute("innerHTML"). Doing that resolved my issue. I am now able to retrieve the values I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else having this issue can try findElement(By.xpath(...)) instead of By.className.
My code was also returning a promise, and I could not get it to work with findElement(By.className)('someClassName') even when I used getText() and getAttribute() and was searching for an element with a unique className.  
Not an ideal solution, but when I switched to findElement(By.xpath)('/html/body/pathToElement').getText() it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32322894)